# Monotouch EventKit - Not Able To Retrieve EventIdentifier

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, eventkit

I am using the example found here : http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_eventkit#4.3.creating-an-event-programmatically

I asked Xamarin and they said I was supposed to use `EventIdentifier` instead of `CalendarItemIdentifier` - However, when you look up an event the way they say (startDate, endDate, and Calendar)

Calendar items don't have an `EventIdentifier`property, and I'm not sure how to cast that or what I'm supposed to do there.

Here's a basic example of what I am doing. The problem is that when I go to look up an event by the identifier it doesn't exist since it's a `CalendarItemIdentifier` instead of an `EventIdentifier`

```
public string CreateDefaultEvent ()
        {
            // Creating an event for demonstration purposes
            // This is the sample code from your website to create an event programmatically
            EKEvent newEvent = EKEvent.FromStore ( Application.AppEventStore );
            // set the alarm for 10 minutes from now
            newEvent.AddAlarm ( EKAlarm.FromDate ( DateTime.Now.AddMinutes ( 10 ) ) );
            // make the event start 20 minutes from now and last 30 minutes
            newEvent.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes ( 20 );
            newEvent.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes ( 50 );
            newEvent.Title = "Get outside and do some exercise!";
            newEvent.Notes = "This is your motivational event to go and do 30 minutes of exercise. Super important. Do this.";
            newEvent.Calendar = Application.AppEventStore.DefaultCalendarForNewEvents;

            NSError e;
            Application.AppEventStore.SaveEvent ( newEvent, EKSpan.ThisEvent, out e );
            Console.WriteLine ("Event Saved, ID: " + newEvent.CalendarItemIdentifier);
            return newEvent.CalendarItemIdentifier;
        }

        public string RetrieveCreatedEvent (string _eventIdentifier)
        {
            // We will just return the event's notes to see if we got a valid event
            EKEvent savedEvent = Application.AppEventStore.EventFromIdentifier (_eventIdentifier);
            return savedEvent.Notes;
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DreamWalker - Please don't edit posts unless you're helping significantly. Removing "Thanks" at the bottom is not a viable edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to get the event you have to do this:

```
NSPredicate query = Util.MyEventStore.PredicateForEvents (Util.DateTimeToNSDate(startDate), Util.DateTimeToNSDate(endDate), null);
//EKCalendarItem[] eventArrary = Util.MyEventStore.EventsMatching (query);
EKEvent[] eventArrary = Util.MyEventStore.EventsMatching (query);
```

I don't know why I initially turned this to a `EKCalendarItem[]` but, you have to use an `EKEvent`